# Just had engine rebuilt, since that i had to replace fuel pump, now heater is blowing and no hot air. Could this be due to the rebuild done?

Tags: engine, coolant, heater, rebuild

i just had an engine rebuild and since have had several minor but potentially expensive issues.  Can a heater be affected by an engine rebuild?  I picked it up 3 weeks ago and was informed that if my car continues to smoke after two weeks to return to the mechanic.  It was smoking worse than it did prior to the rebuild.  They kept it a few more weeks and conducted an oil change after replacing the valve cover.  I picked it up and no more smoking however my heater blew cold air, no heat.  When i returned the car again it had low coolant.  I picked it up and they said the heater was working and they just needed to fill the coolant.  I went home and the next day i noticed oil on my driveway and looked under my car and it was clearly leaking oil.

Took my car back and they said it was a plug that needed replaced. They told me today for the heater repairs, it will cost roughly 335.00 to get the heater door/blend or actuator replaced?  I'm so very frustrated.  My car has been there since September and off and on the past two weeks.  i spent 4500.00 on engine rebuild, then roughly 700 for the fuel pump replacement, now it will be about 335.00 for my heater.

Comment: I would strongly suggest trying a different mechanic, at least for the heater diagnosis.